# GCOV on Linux kernel

Tags: kernel, arm, gcov

I am working on Linux kernel 3.0.35 for ARM(IMX6). Successfully cross compiled kernel with GCOV support. However .gcno files are created with names staring with .tmp_ (ex: .tmp_fork.gcno) . Is this the expected result ?

Then mounted debugfs uImage but /sys/kernel/debug/gcov/ has only reset file. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the config file.

```
CONFIG_MODVERSIONS=y    // (Because of this, ".tmp_" seems to be added.)
```

Disabling it, you will find `fork.gcno`.